Plotting two Signals on the same graph in Matlab, with different x-axis values

The first graph is a continuous signal and has the values
t = linspace(0,.030);  % 30 milliseconds
xa = 3*sin(100*pi*t); 


and the second is a discrete signal sampled at Fs = 300 s/s

 n =[0:1:6];
xn = 3*sin((pi/3)*n);

Is there anyway to show the two graphs on the same plot while preserving their outputs
hold on/hold off does not accomplish what i'm looking for.
